# MATLAB cell to string

Tags: excel, matlab, casting, cell

I am trying to read an excel sheet and then and find cells that are not empty and have date information in them by finding two '/' in a string
but matlab keeps to erroring on handling cell type
"Undefined operator '~=' for input arguments of type 'cell'."
"Undefined function 'string' for input arguments of type 'cell'."
"Undefined function 'char' for input arguments of type 'cell'."

```
MyFolderInfo = dir('C:\');  

filename = 'Export.xls';
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread(filename,'A1:G200'); 

for i = 1:length(txt)
    if ~isnan(raw(i,1))
        if sum(ismember(char(raw(i,1)),'/')) == 2 
            A(i,1) = raw(i,1);
        end
    end
end
```

please help fixing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code.  Since `raw` is a cell array, you can't run `isnan` on it, `isnan` is for numerical arrays.  Since all you're interested in is cells with text in them, you don't need to use `raw` at all, any blank cells will not be present in `txt`.

My approach is to create a logical array, `has_2_slashes`, and then use it to extract the elements from `raw` that have two slashes in them.

Here is my code.  I generalized it to read multiple columns since your original code only seemed to be written to handle one column.

```
filename = 'Export.xls';
[~, ~, raw] = xlsread(filename, 'A1:G200'); 

[num_rows, num_cols] = size(raw);
has_2_slashes = false(num_rows, num_cols);
for row = 1:num_rows
   for col = 1:num_cols
      has_2_slashes(row, col) = sum(ismember(raw{row, col}, '/')) == 2;
   end
end

A = raw(has_2_slashes);
```

Comment: the probelm is that i do want to use the numerical data after filtering only rows with dates in them, but using this method the data is shfted between the num and txt matrixes hence i was trying to use the raw data

Comment: I modified my code to work with the raw data instead of just the text data.  It turns out that ismember can deal with numerical data as well as character data, so the change was very minimal.

Answer (score 1):

```
cellfun(@numel,strfind(txt,'/'))
```

should give you a numerical array where the (i,j)th element contains the number of slashes. For example,

```
>> cellfun(@numel,strfind({'a','b';'/','/abc/'},'/'))
ans =
     0     0
     1     2
```

The key here is to use `strfind`.

Now you may want to expand a bit in your question on what you intend to do next with `txt` -- in other words, specify desired output more, which is always a good thing to do. If you intend to read the dates, it may be better to just read it upfront, for example by using `regexp` or `datetime` as opposed to getting an array which can then map to where the dates are. As is, using `ans>=2` next gives you the logical array that can let you extract the matched entries.